# Same onClick method for two LinearLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have two `LinearLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:onClick="viewTipsDetail">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@mipmap/img_breakfast" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Đừng bỏ bữa sáng"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Các nghiên cứu cho thấy bữa sáng là một những điê"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:onClick="viewTipsDetail">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@mipmap/img_waterglass" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Uống đủ nước"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity=""
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="Bổ sung đủ nước cho cơ thể, ngay cả các bạn làm việc trong môi trường máy lạnh hoặc ngoài trời. Việc mất nước có thể khiến bạn căng thẳng, khó tập trung vào công việc"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I'm going to plan implement an `onClickEvent` with same method for both of them. In this occasion, the event will call `viewTipsDetail()` method. So how can I get the image src, the text in specific `LinearLayout` with only one method? And is there any possible way to auto-generate a `LinearLayout` like this with given detail?

This is sample, I'm going to use more `LinearLayout` than this, so what I need in general is a possible method for getting detail in specific `LinearLayout`.

Comment: why you are not using onClickListener to achieve this?

Comment: take a diffrent `id` of linear layout and manage a `onClickListnere`

Comment: This is sample, there will be a lot of LinearLayout, how can I write method for all of them?

Comment: Will you be adding more LinearLayout from xml or programmatically?

Comment: Yes, of course. There will be more LinearLayout, that why I can not use id and write an onClick event for all of them

Comment: Are you adding them from xml or java?

Comment: I'm plan to add them from java. With information received from server.

Comment: If you planning to do that way then pls update your question. So one can help that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
        id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        onClick="onLayoutClick"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        onClick="onLayoutClick"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

In code:

```
@Override
public void onLayoutClick(View view) {
    // click click
    // view.getTag()
}
```

Or just use list view for achieve that...

Comment: so we use switch case ? with the id?

Comment: I dont understand. Can u be more detailed?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe your approach is wrong and excessive?

Comment: Because, there will be a lot of child layout, so how can I write an onClick event for all of them?

Comment: it's a rule brother without given id you can not access @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM

Comment: so how can I write specific method for each new layout would be created? There is no general way to do this?

Comment: But why you doing that? Many child layout - for what? Give me example to understand your idea :)

Comment: I'm going to receive information from server. And with information. I want to have a child layout like that to display them in short. When people click on the layout, it will transfer to a new activity with full information. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm thinking about ListView

Comment: Ofcourse! You should do that with RecyclerView (typical list with items). You can add unspecified ammount of items and add click listener on each other. Listener can return your "full_info_id" or whatever that identify clicked item :)

Comment: not use Listview you can use `Recyclerview` it's a batter for you @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM

Comment: I will take a look. I only know how to use LinearLayout and RelativeLayout now, so mostly I use them. I will see RecylerView

Comment: Anyway - if you wanted to realize your idea you should put your LinearLayouts in ScrollView to scroll them vertically. It's possible, but you will spend too much effort for that simple thing.

Comment: @NguyenHoangVu-K11FUGHCM refer this link for batter understanding `recyclerview` :  https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Comment: Oke, thanks for your support guys :D I will see and try to apply recylerview.